# UITableViewController executes delate functions before network request finishes

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, uitableview, afnetworking

I'm having trouble trying to populate a `UITableView` with the results of a network request. It seems that my code is alright as it works perfectly when my network is speedy, however, when it's not, the function 
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath-` still executes, which results in a bad access error. I presume that this is because the array that the aforesaid function attempts to utilize has not been populated. This brings me to my question: Is there anyway that I can have the `UITableView` delegate methods delayed to avoid this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AlbumsCell";
//UITableViewCell *basicCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

AlbumsCell *cell = (AlbumsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    **// Here is where the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2 address=0x8)**
    cell = [[[AlbumsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

    Album *album = [_albums objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [cell setAlbum:album];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your delegate methods to handle the network request for 'in progress' status as well. And once the you get your response, call the `reloadData` on tableview which will reload the table with proper data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AlbumsCell";
//UITableViewCell *basicCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    AlbumsCell *cell = (AlbumsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        **// Here is where the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2 address=0x8)**
        cell = [[[AlbumsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ((_albums) && ([_albums count] > [indexPath row])) {
        Album *album = [_albums objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [cell setAlbum:album];
    } else {
    //show some loading message in the cell
    }

    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: I actually tried something similar before. I tried your code just now and it gives me the EXC_BAD_ACCESS at if ((_albums) && ([_albums count] > [indexPath row])) most times when I run my application. I am totally lost now. Why does this happen? At first I thought that it was because of an network execution but now I am not so sure as this error is not the result of me trying to access any indexes in the array.

Comment: Is it going inside the if condition? When exactly is it crashing? and what is the complete crash message?

Comment: The actual declaration of the condition is where it crashes (if ((_albums) && ([_albums count] > [indexPath row])) { ). I thought that maybe it was because I didn't correctly retain my array but if that were the case then why does this crash not occur everything?

Comment: Have you checked AlbumsCell class? Also is there anything else in the method  [cell setAlbum:album]; which could cause an issue? This could be a memory issue also as some value is getting released at times. Verify all the memory allocation and release statements as well.